# Resetting scope between back and forward history movement between views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

the first time the view loads the variables are set to default values. If you change the scope variable counter and go back history and come back again why is the scope variable not reset again as this controller would suggest?

```
.controller('VisitorCtrl', function ( $scope, $stateParams ) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    .... bla la bla
});
```

So in my template you can set the scope by choosing a number. I then test it by going back in history one step (*back button in browser*). then come back by following the link that takes me to this view. then the scope is what it was when I set it the first time?

Comment: Just passed the value between the links in url

Answer (score 0):

you could set the `cache-view` attribute to `false` which force rebuild the DOM and reset controller when re-entering the view, see [ion-nav-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/):

```
<ion-view view-title="My Page" cache-view="false">
    ...
</ion-nav-view>
```